# JQuery Dynamic Element - In DOM but unable to bind

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I'm new to using JQuery so bear with me.

I had implmented some code based on a js file that I found online which enables a series of div tags within a nested structure on my page to step through and show each one individually on the page. This all works great when I define the div tags as static entries in the masterpage. I should add that this is being implemented in a SharePoint master page.

Ultimately though, with a static collection of div tags ideally containing an image with some descriptive text, and a hyperlink its not very flexible. Roll on my changes to make this a little more configurable. I have implemented some additional code that will read from a SharePoint list via an ajax call to the lists web service. For each entry in the list I am building a div tag that contains the information required dynamically. For testing, I am only pulling the title through at present.

I have used the following code:

```
    $('#beltDiv').append(divHTML)
```

to append the divs in the loop that are created to my nested structure on the page. I figured that this would cause the fade code to work as expected but I was wrong. It doesn't do anything at all.

When check the source on the page, the div tags are not shown. They are however available in the DOM model when viewed through the IE developer toolbar.

The issue (I think) looks to be that the initiation of the featureFade code is not working due to the div tags being unavailable. Is there a way to address this? The code used is shown below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">         
$(document).ready(function() {

    var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>Carousel Items</listName> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                       </ViewFields> \
                    </viewFields> \
                </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({
        url: "_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });

});

function processResult(xData, status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {          

    var divHTML = "<div id=\"divPanel_" +  $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "\" class=\"panel\" style=\"background:url('http://devSP2010/sites/SPSOPS/Style Library/SharePointOps/Images/01.jpg') no-repeat; width:650px; height:55px;\"><div><div class=\"content\"><div><P><A style=\"COLOR: #cc0000\" href=\"www.google.com\">" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</A></P><P>&nbsp;</P><P>&nbsp;</P><P>&nbsp;</P><P>&nbsp;</P></div></div></div></div>";
    $("#beltDiv").append(divHTML);      

    });
}

    featureFade.setup({
        galleryid: 'headlines',
        beltclass: 'belt',
        panelclass: 'panel',
        autostep: { enable: true, moveby: 1, pause: 10000 },
        panelbehavior: { speed: 1000, wraparound: true },
        stepImgIDs: ["ftOne", "ftTwo", "ftThree", "ftFour","ftFive"],
        defaultButtons: { itemOn: "Style Library/SharePointOps/Images/dotOn.png", itemOff: "Style Library/SharePointOps/Images/dotOff.png" }
    });
```

The section where the div tags are dynamically appended is shown below. I've commented out the static div tags that work as expected. The only change is that these are implmented by the JQuery logic:

```
    <div class="homeFeature" style="display:inline-block">
        <div id="headlines" class="headlines">
            <div id="beltDiv" class="belt">
                <!--
                <div id="divPanel_ct01" class="panel" style="position:absolute;background-image:url('http://devsp2010/sites/spsops/Style Library/SharePointOps/Images/01.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat">Static Test 1</div>
                <div id="divPanel_ct02" class="panel" style="position:absolute;background-image:url('http://devsp2010/sites/spsops/Style Library/SharePointOps/Images/02.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat">Static Test 2</div>
                -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm stumped as to why it's not recognising the dynamically added elements in the DOM. Any help would be greatly appreciated on this.

I'm happy to provide any further information on this.

Thanks in advance,

Grant

Further to the answer recieved: I have modified the function call:

```
    function processResult(xData, status) 
{
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(
        function() 
        {           
            /*alert($(this).attr("ows_ImagePath"));*/
            var divHTML = "<div id=\"divPanel_" +  $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "\" class=\"panel\" style=\"background:url('http://devSP2010/sites/SPSOPS/Style Library/SharePointOps/Images/ClydePort01big.jpg') no-repeat; width:650px; height:55px;\"><div><div class=\"content\"><div><P><A style=\"COLOR: #cc0000\" href=\"www.google.com\">" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</A></P><P>&nbsp;</P><P>&nbsp;</P><P>&nbsp;</P><P>&nbsp;</P></div></div></div></div>";
            $("#beltDiv").append(divHTML);      
        }
    );

    featureFade.setup(
        {
            galleryid: 'headlines',
            beltclass: 'belt',
            panelclass: 'panel',
            autostep: { enable: true, moveby: 1, pause: 10000 },
            panelbehavior: { speed: 1000, wraparound: true },
            stepImgIDs: ["ftOne", "ftTwo", "ftThree", "ftFour","ftFive"],
            defaultButtons: { itemOn: "Style Library/SharePointOps/Images/dotOn.png", itemOff: "Style Library/SharePointOps/Images/dotOff.png" }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: i cant tell by looking at that code what it should be finding and is not. provide more detail

Comment: Fair point. I have updated with the nested div structure to which the dynamic elements are appended.

Comment: i cant tell with the tabbing if you did this right. i think not. either that, or you are missing a closing brace of the processResult function.

Comment: updated to tab code. It does now appear to be getting a new null object error message for a part of the script file itemFade.js whichcontains the featureFade logic. It looks as though it is unable to find the div with the ID=headlines.

Answer (score 0):

ok this is simple, your `featureFade` object is created before the DOM is appended.

why? because `processResult` is callback for an async server call, so to fix this you need to move the `featureFade` init to the end of the `processResult` function.

Comment: Added modified function above. Is this what you mean. This isn't returning any sign of the divs at all on the page. I may have misread the post you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - SharePoint 2010 has a new client object model that makes calling web services a whole lot easier

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("/");
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Carousel Items');   
var q = "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields></View>";    
camlQuery.set_viewXml(q);
var listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(listItems, 'Include(Title)'); 
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(sender, args) {
    var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext())  {
        var title = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item("Title");
        //do your stuff
    }
}, function(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
});
```